# класс map и пользовательские типы

Tags: c++

подскажите как отобразить элементы map. Подскажите как разобраться с ошибкой.

```
class test1
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    test1() {};
    test1(std::string name, int age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
    bool operator < (const test1 & a) const
    {
        return (this->name < a.name) && (this->age < a.age);
    }

    std::string GetName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int GetAge()
    {
        return this->age;
    }

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const test1 & a)
    {
        os << "name: " << a.GetName() << " " << "age : " << a.GetAge();
        return os;
    }
};

class test2
{
private:
    std::string bag;
    std::string color;
public:
    test2() {};
    test2(std::string bagName, std::string color)
    {
        this->bag = bagName;
        this->color = color;
    }
    std::string GetBag()
    {
        return this->bag;
    }
    std::string Color()
    {
        return this->color;
    }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const test2 & a)
    {
        os << "name: " << a.GetBag() << " " << "age : " << a.Color();
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::map<test1, test2> myMap;
    test1 user1{ "John", 20 };
    test2 inventory{ "Daykine", "red" };
    myMap.emplace(user1, inventory);

    test1 user2{ "Victor", 20 };
    test2 inventory2{ "Daykine", "blue" };
    myMap.emplace(user2, inventory2);

    for (auto & item : myMap)
    {
        cout << item.first; // тут ошибка
        cout << item.second;// хотя все перегрузил
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Функции-друзья не являются членами класса. Так что что это за вызов `GetName()` болтается у вас внутри `operator <<` компилятору не понятно. Зачем вы вообще передавали туда параметр `a`, если он нигде не используется? И что такое `ostream`? Почему не `std::ostream`? У вас везде `std::`, а здесь вдруг нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### У вас ошибка в неверной сигнатуре оператора для вывода.

Попробуйте в операторе вывода

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream os, const test1 & a)
{
    os << "name: " << GetName() << " " << "age : " << GetAge();
    return os;
}
```

заменить сигнатуру на

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const test1 & a)
```

Первый аргумент `ostream &os` теперь ссылка (а не по значению `ostream os`, как было у вас).

Также у вас там ещё пачка ошибок. Я [исправил](http://cpp.sh/2on26) код.

Что изменено:

1. Поправлен вызов GetName() на a.GetName() и аналогичные,
2. Поправлено пространство имён std
3. Поправлена ссылка в операторе вывода
4. Поправлены const квалификаторы у ваших функций )

Comment: Ваш совет помог исправить первыю проблему. А вотрая осталась                                 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2352 'test1::GetAge': illegal call of non-static member function test c:\users\mazur\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\test\test\test.cpp 41

Comment: недопустимый вызов нестатической функции-члена, не могу разобраться что ему не нравится

Comment: не просто  `GetName()` и `GetAge()`, а `a.GetName()` и `a.GetAge()`

Comment: Но сделать `a.GeName()` не получится - не позволит const-квалификация.

Comment: Исправил указанные ошибки.           Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2662 'int test1::GetAge(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const test1' to 'test1 &' test c:\users\mazur\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\test\test\test.cpp

Comment: как решить проблему с const?

Comment: Смотрите исправленный код в ответе.

Comment: спасибо, проблема решена.